Size of the set of all $f:${$1,2,3,4,5,6$} $\rightarrow$ {$1,2,3,4,5,6$} s.t. $\forall n \in${$1,2,3,4,5,6$} $f(n) \neq n$ and $f(f(f(f(f(f(n))))))=n$
I considered the smaller problem where the set instead has $4$ elements and $f(f(f(f(n))))=n$, and after listing all of the possibilities I counted a total of $9$.
That immediately tells me that the answer for a question of this kind will not necessarily be a factorial number, which is perhaps what a naïve first instinct might make one think (in fact, everyone in the comments section of the social media post I ripped this problem from keeps insisting that the answer is $5!$ or $6!$, likely reasoning too hastily and uncarefully).
I repeated this process for the case where we have a set with $5$ elements and $f(f(f(f(f(n)))))=n$, and I counted a total of $44$ possibilities.
It's also worth noting that in the case where we have $3$ elements and $f(f(f(n)))=n$ we of course only have $2$ possibilities. Thus, the sequence seems to go: $2,9,44$
Based on an intuition regarding symmetry, I'm willing to bet that if $m$ is the number of elements in our set then the answer as to the cardinality of the set of $f$ will always be divisible by $m-1$
Thus, I'm willing to bet that the answer to this question is divisible by $5$.
Unfortunately, this is the closest I've gotten to making progress. I really don't even know how to start.
However, after running my partial sequence ($A000166$) through the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, it seems to make sense to believe that what we're dealing with here are in fact the subfactorial numbers. It makes so much sense, in fact, that I'm almost certain this is the case, in which case the answer to this question would be $!6=265$.
If that ends up being the case, maybe this problem could be a good way for me to be introduced to the subfactorial numbers and the theory behind them.

As noted in the comments, I made some mistakes in my intuition-building examples.
Most importantly, I should make it clear that we're actually dealing with this sequence ($A261531$) instead.
In the case with $5$ elements, the two integer sequences are no longer identical and it already starts to become important to realize that the subfactorial number $!5=44$ of permutations I initially counted includes permutations that fail to satisfy $f(f(f(f(f(n)))))=n$. This makes the cases of $5$ or more elements fundamentally different from the cases of $4$ or fewer elements.

When you say you took 5 elements did you use $f^6(n)=n$ or $f^5(n)=n$

The latter. In each of the smaller intuition-building cases I always adjusted the number of iterations of the function according to the size of the set.

Please mention that in the question its a bit ambiguous

I indeed did type my answer too quickly :D. So we should count the number of derangements of cycle type $(4, 2)$ and subtract that from $!6$.

Your count for $n=5$ is wrong, there are only 24 such derangements. The general sequence is A261431.

@anankElpis does that mean that 20 of the possibilities I counted will fail to satisfy $f(f(f(f(f(n)))))=n$?

Yes, those should be exactly the permutations that can be written as a disjoint product of a two-cycle and a three-cycle, which have order 6.

I count $175$: there are $120$ $6$-cycles, $40$ products of two disjoint $3$-cycles, and $15$ products of three transpositions. These are precisely the permutations of six elements with no fixed points and order dividing $6$.

@ArturoMagidin There are only 40 products of two disjoint 3-cycles: Pick $f(1)$ and $f(f(1))$ for $5\cdot 4$ options for the first cycle, and one of $2$ orientations for the remaining triple.

@anankElpis Yes, I fixed that. I had the right formula, but did the mental arithmetic wrong on the first pass.

A permutation of six elements has order dividing six if and only if it is one of the following:

The identity permutation.
A product of one, two, or three disjoint transpositions.
A product of one or two disjoint $3$-cycles.
A product of a transposition and a disjoint $3$-cycle.
A $6$-cycle.

Of these, the only ones without fixed points are the products of three transpositions, products of two $3$-cycles, and the $6$-cycles.
The number of $6$-cycles is $6!/6=5!=120$. Just list the numbers in order to create the cycle, each one appears six times,
The number of products of two $3$-cycles is $6!/(3)^22=40$. List the numbers in order, divide them with first three and last three. Each $3$-cycle occurs $3$ times (hence the $3^2$), and the product occurs twice (depending on the order of the cycles, hence the $2$).
The number of products of three transpositions is $6!/(2)^33!=15$. (Each transposition can be written two ways, hence the $2^3$, and we can write the product of the three transpositions in $3!$ ways).
So the total number is $175$.

Alternatively, if the OP knows the derangement numbers, 265 derangements minus $90$ derangements of order $4$.

To generalise as you do, you are asking for a set $A$ of finite order $m$, the number of maps $f:A\to{A}$ satisfying $\forall{a}\in{A}:f(a)\neq{a}$ and $\forall{a}\in{A}:f^m(a)=a$. The second condition implies that $f$ is bijective, so we are counting certain permutations of$~A$.
Yes, the answers for $m=2,3,4$ are respectively $1,2,9$, and yes the permutations counted here are all derangements (because that is what the first condition says). But no, for $m=5$ the answer is not $44$ but $24$, and not all derangements are counted here. That is because not all derangements $f$ of a $5$-element set satisfy the second condition $f^5=I$. Indeed a permutation like $(1~2~3)(4~5)$ is a derangement (it fixes none of the $5$ elements) but its fifth power is $(1~3~2)(4~5)$ which is not the identity. In fact for $m=5$ one is only counting permutation that are $5$-cycles, like $(1~4~5~3~2)$, of which there are just $24$.
So to find the right number for $m=6$, one must know the valid cycle types and for each one count the permutations of that type. Since $1$-cycles are forbidden by the first condition, and all cycle lengths must divide $m=6$ by the second condition, we just find cycle types $(6)$, $(3,3)$ and $(2,2,2)$. For each cycle type the number of permutations is given by a simple formula, which for those three types respectively gives $\frac{6!}6=120$, $\frac{6!}{3\times3\times2!}=40$, and $\frac{6!}{2\times2\times2\times3!}=15$, for $120+40+15=175$ derangements of order dividing $6$ in all.
